# how to access resources(Excel file) in jar file

Tags: java, embedded-resource

Hi i have exported my java project as executable jar file. inside my project I am accessing a Excel file containing some data. Now I am not able to access the Excel file when I am trying to access the file.

My project structure is:
Java_Project_Folder
 **- src_Folder

 - resources_Folder(Containing excel file)**

I am accessing the excel file like

```
FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"Excel.xlsx"));
```

I have tried accessing this file using `getResourceAsStream` like:

```
FileInputStream file=(FileInputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream
("/resources/Excel.xlsx");
```

But i am getting in is null exception. whats wrong can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  Typically, your resources folder should not be inside your code src folder.

Comment: The second snippet is on the right track, except you won't get a FileInputStream, since the resource is inside the jar, but an InputStream. Show us the contents of the jar file (with jar tvf yourfile.jar)

Comment: @torquestomp: why shouldn't it, since the OP wants this folder to be part of the jar file?

Comment: Resources in a Jar are known as an [tag:embedded-resource].  Those resources must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: Hi Jayesh thanks i have tried your solution and it is working now. For those for future reference i will summarize it. You need to include the resource folder in your build path by following the steps as given above. then you need to use the getResourceAsStream to refer to the resource file like this : InputStream file= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resource.xlsx"); Also make sure that the resource file is exported in the jar which you have exported. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it is working for me.

My Test1 class is in default package, just check where your accessing class is in any package, if it is then go back to exact resource folder from classpath like this "../"

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();  
    }
    Test1(){
        BufferedInputStream file= (BufferedInputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/a.txt");
        try {
            System.out.println((char)file.read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution. it is running from my java project. but when i am exporting it to jar file then it is not working. any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: While Creating Jar from Eclipse, Make sure you are checking the checkbox "Add Directory Entries", can you check this once.

Comment: how you are creating a JAR file? Try creating once with Eclipse if you are not creating by Eclipse and Right Click - > Export As -> JAR File -> when box open, you can see Add Directory entries at bottom, check the box, default not checked. try once.

Comment: i have used eclipse to make jar. i am using runnable jar option while exporting

Comment: I think you can use similar option there, Runnable JAR file -> Package required libraries into generated JAR, check this box and try once.

Comment: Also, can you just extract generated jar to check whether entries in JAR is correctly placed.

Comment: please refer my additional comments above. i have tried your solution and it has worked.

Answer (score 3):

I bet you have no package called `resources` in your project.

Trying to use [Class.#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is the way to go. But this method does not return a `FileInputStream`. It returns an `InputStream` wich is an interface.

You should be passing the absolute name of the resource

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("my/pack/age/Excel.xlsx");
```

where the excel file is located in the directory

```
resources/my/pack/age
```

Comment: you are correct it seems the resources folder didn't got exported. i have tried exporting my java project from eclipse as runnable jar file by extracting all the required libraries into generated jar file. how should i include my resources folder to the jar file in export resources as runnable jar file through eclipse???

Comment: @MrunalGosar the folders `src` and `resources` as of any other forlder you define in eclipse as source folder is never exported to the jar file. Its purpose is only for organisation. What gets exported is the packages. so if you have a package `foo.bar` inside the folder `resources` then only `foo/bar` will be exported, and calls to `getResourceAsStream` has to start with `foo/bar` not `resources/foo/bar`. If you export the hole project then all source folders will be exported by default.

Comment: i had exported the whole project. when we export our java project as runnable jar i guess it exports the whole java project. so how should i include the resources folder in the jar?

Comment: @MrunalGosar Just to make it clear, you will not open the jar file with a zip tool and file a folder named `resources` in it. If the content of the folder `resources` is not exported then it is most likely that this folder is not used as a `source folder` (see if has normal folder icon or a folder icon with a java package overley, the later is the correct one). If `resources` is not a `source folder` then you should turn it into one. To do so, right click on the folder `resources` then go to `Build Path` then click `Use as Source Folder`. Retry the export.

Comment: i have tried as you said and i have used the getResourceAsStream method to try to access the excel file from inside jar file. now it is working when i am running it from my java project. but when i am running it by exporting it in runnable jar it is not working. this is what i have tried : InputStream file= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../../GSUIControls.xlsx"); whats wrong in here?

Comment: @MrunalGosar There should be no difference between project run and jar run provided that the resource is exported. `getResourceAsStream` looks for the resource in the class path. Open your jar with a zip tool (winrar or 7zip for example) and see if the resource is there and whether the path `../../../../GSUIControls.xlsx` is correct relativ to the class where you try to load it. I can't say whether it is correct or not since I don't know your package structure and from witch class you are trying to load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33976/discussion-between-mrunal-gosar-and-a4l)

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to include the excel file itself in your project.  You can create a resources folder like you show, but to make sure this gets included in your jar, you add the resources folder in along with your source code files so that it gets built into the jar.

Then

```
InputStream excelContent = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Excel.xlsx");
```

should work.  From one post at least, the leading forward slash may also mess things up if you use the ClassLoader.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c.xml")  ==> a/b/c.xml
getClass().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c.xml")  ==> com/example/a/b/c.xml
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c.xml")  ==> a/b/c.xml
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c.xml")  ==> Incorrect
```

ref: [getResourceAsStream fails under new environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238562/getresourceasstream-fails-under-new-environment)

Also in eclipse you can set the resources folder as a source folder like this:

in the properties of your eclipse project, go to java build path, select sources, and check to see if all needed source fodlers are added (as source folders). If some are missing, just add them manually using add sources... button

ref: [Java Resources Folder Error In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377995/java-resources-folder-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi @Ted i am using eclipse to make the runnable jar file by extracting all the required libraries in to generated jar file. now how should i make eclipse to include the resources folder into generated jar file????

Comment: If you mark rsc as a source folder Eclipse will copy its contents to the output directory. Or you could just move rsc under src if you want to group the resources in the output.

Answer (score 0):

> FileInputStream file= (FileInputStream)
>   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Excel.xlsx");

Why do you need FileInputStream? Use

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream..
```

Secondly use "resources/Excel.xlsx"
Thirdly when constructing file like this

> new
>   File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"Excel.xlsx"));

is hard to control slashes. use

```
new File("parent (userdir property)", "child (resources\Excel.xlsx)")
```

Comment: Hi @cdkrot the constructor of XSSFWorkBook of POI library asks for an instance of FileInputStream so how should i go about that. Also can you guide me to the solution where i can run the same piece of code from jar as well as from outside of jar i.e as java project in eclipse?