# How to read an excel file inside the jar?

Tags: java, import-from-excel

I have a Sample.jar in my build path which contains only an excel file abc.xls under src. How do I read this into a FileInputStream in my java application?

Also, I have to deliver my project as a jar. This jar must be able to read the excel file present in Sample.jar.

Comment: if it's on the classpath then you can use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`

Comment: i think you should try this one.

[try it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774637/how-to-access-resourcesexcel-file-in-jar-file